# Haxe - Class not found : Test

Tags: ubuntu, haxe

I try to use haxe for the first time. I'm with ubuntu. 
I follow this tutorial : http://haxe.org/doc/build/haxe_ubuntu_build

I have a : compile.hxml

```
 -swf test.swf
 -main Test
```

and Test.hs

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        trace("Hello World !");
    }
}
```

But when I try to compile :

```
~/dev/workspace/haxe$ haxe compile.hxml 
Class not found : Test
```

I've put the path en the ./bachrc

```
export HAXE_HOME=/usr/local/haxe
export HAXE_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/haxe/std:. # the ':.' part is important
PATH=$PATH:$HAXE_LIBRARY_PATH:$HAXE_HOME/bin
```

And when I looking if the path exist :

```
~$ echo $HAXE_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/haxe/std:.

~$ ls /usr/local/haxe/std
Array.hx  cs            Enum.hx       flash   IntIterator.hx  Lambda.hx  Math.hx  Reflect.hx   StringBuf.hx    sys     Type.hx
Class.hx  Date.hx       EnumValue.hx  flash8  java            List.hx    neko     Std.hx       String.hx       Sys.hx  Xml.hx
cpp       DateTools.hx  EReg.hx       haxe    js              Map.hx     php      StdTypes.hx  StringTools.hx  tools
```

The haxe version is :

- Haxe Compiler 3.0.0
- NekoVM 2.0.0

There is a note in the tutorial :
"Since Haxe3 r6354 HAXE_LIBRARY_PATH is named HAXE_STD_PATH"
But I've try to change it without any change with my error.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your file actually "Test.hs"? It should be "Test.hx", but I'm not sure if that's just a typo in your question. You can also use "haxe -v compile.hxml" to get more verbose output, including which class paths are being looked up

Comment: oooo, well. You solve my problem and I feel stupid :) Just change the extention do the work. Thanks!

Comment: Haha no need to feel stupid.  With learning new languages there are lots of little "gotchas" that you can easily miss. Good luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Test.hs" should be "Test.hx" :)